# Default.aspx becomes Default just extension less

Tags: c#, webforms

this my project link https://github.com/karlosRivera/Inject-CountryCode-in-URL

where i have few links like home, about and contact. when click on home then Default.aspx becomes Default just extension less and asp.net could not load page. other contact and about page is loading fine

anyone can see my project code and tell me where i made the mistake.

i implement 3 iis rewrite rule and those are

```
  <rule name="Always redirect country root extensionless path to index.aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^[a-z]{2}" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^[a-z]{2}" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}/index.aspx" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Always redirect root extensionless path to index.aspx" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/index.aspx" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="Rewrite rule for Redirecting countries" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*.aspx" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="[a-z]{2}/(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{tolower:{C:1}}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

are these rules are causing problem? please push me to right direction. thanks

Comment: Looks like you doing a lot of weird redirecting which is why you lose the extension.. Either a) remove the rewrite rules entirely and use default pages, or b) create a folder called Default from where setup yet another redirect, or c) try using official url rewrite module: https://tecadmin.net/enable-url-rewrite-iis/

Comment: I have used few url rewrite rule because i have added country code in url like http://www.mysite/gb/default.aspx so i need to inform server that there no folder called gb. That is why i have to use iis rewrite rule. Which rule u think weird ?

Comment: May be not so weird.. Try to add another Rewrite from Default to Default.aspx.. Or stick with redirects instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/10159910/3254405.. Since it's MVC you can redirect from controllers or uncomment routes in your routes config.. Consider creating country folders, good for SEO..

Comment: You're talking about Default.aspx but the rules seem to say index.aspx. Is that right?